# CLang compilation failed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, clang

I faced following error while compiling main.m (Objective-C)
I am using makefile to build this file.

```
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -Wall -DDEBUG=1 -g -o main.o main.m -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -F/Volumes/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

In file included from main.m:9:
In file

 included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:138:
    In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAppleEventDescriptor.h:7:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:64:10: fatal error: 
          'ImageIO/ImageIO.h' file not found
    #include <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I do not know why this `ImageIO/ImageIO.h` is not found. What is the reason behind this?
Additionally I would like to know how to make Clang to look into the Frameworks present in /Volumes/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ **(specified in option -F)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build against the OS X 10.8 SDK from the command-line. The compiler invocation you're after will look something like so:

```
xcrun clang -arch x86_64 -Wall -DDEBUG=1 -g -o main.o main.m -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -isysroot $(xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.8 Path)
```

The `-isysroot` argument to `clang` tells it to treat the given path as the root of the system with respect to the default header and framework search paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Later I figured out that I need to mention it under --sysroot flag. By this, I got the files compiled.